# C#/SQL Switch between sql tables with combobox in a single datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm developing a project but an idea and a doubt came up, instead of putting 3 datagridview on top of each other, and putting visible and invisible, do it automatically in a single datagridview for example, I have a combobox, if you select in combobox the item "People" appears in the "People" database table, but if you select the "Age" table it appears in the same datagridview that table, can someone explain to me how to do this?

Comment: Use a DataAdapter to put the query results into a datatable.  The make the datatable the datasource of the DGV.  The all you have to so is change the query to the database depending on the combobox selection.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?force_isolation=true&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating this method that has a parameter for your table name

*I assume that you are using `sql` as your database*

```
public void SelectData(string tableName)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString")
    {
         cn.Open();
         string query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
         SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter (query, cn);
         DataTable table = new DataTable();
         adapter.Fill(table);

         DataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
}
```

Then put the method above inside the ComboBox `SelectedIndexChanged` event then write

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectData(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the property **AutoGenerateColumns** for datagridview as true.

Now, in the onchange event for dropdown -

1. Remove columns from the datagridview
2. Bind new datasource as per case    (People, Age, etc)

You can add a database call to fetch the new table in the onchange event of dropdown or can bring all tables at once in the beginning and just bind the desired table from the dataset.